# Is it possible for a UITextView to contain multiple pages which can be changed through buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I have a `UITextView` which i want the user to be able to type text and press a **button** (left or right) to change to pages, or maybe swipe if possible; which are still `UITextView`s.

Thanks

Comment: This is unclear. What do you consider a "page" in this context? Something you define? Something that is defined by your dataSource (i.e. a web API)? All characters that overflow the current textView? All characters after a number of characters? Since you can change the text of a UITextView, you can of course implement a button that replaces the text with a different text.

Comment: I define a new page as another UITextView.

Comment: Say I want to make many text views in such are blank. Now I write something on page 1 and save it then write something on page 2. Whenever I click the button when I'm previewing both between the two arrows to change views, it changes between those 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will have calculate text display according to pages then you can change text accordingly on button pressed.

Say you have text like this after making calculation:

```
{
  page1 = ".................................."
  page2 = ".................................."
  page3 = ".................................."
  more ..........................
}
```

Use text to replace in UITextView on button's click

```
yourTextView.text = [yourDictText objectForKey:@"page1"];
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're saying? Can you explain further but in Swift?